# Change const refernece after initilization

Tags: c++, reference

I was advised to use `const` references instead of superfluous getter functions, i.e.

```
class Test {
private:

    std::vector<int> _x;

public:
    const std::vector<int> & x = _x;
}
```

This works nicely, up until one wants to make a copy of a subset:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
    Test() {
        _x = {1,2,3,4};
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> _x;
public:
    const std::vector<int> & x = _x;
    Test getSubset(int i, int j) {
        Test subset = *this;
        subset._x = {_x.begin() + i, _x.begin() + j};
        return subset;
    }; 
    void test() {
        std::cout << "x size: "    <<  x.size() 
                  << ", _x size: " << _x.size() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main( ){
    Test t;
    t.test();
    Test t2 = t.getSubset(1,2);
    t2.test();
}
```

This outputs:

```
x size: 4, _x size: 4
x size: 4, _x size: 1
```

Now, the returned subset has a `_x` with a smaller size, but `x` with the size of the initial vector.

What are some ways to overcome this problem? I can of course define actual getter functions, but I'm curios to hear if there are more obvious solutions.

Comment: A proper constructor.

Comment: The constructor aside, a `std::vector` is a poor choice of data structure to represent a (sub)set. (I’d call that a range, a view or some such.)

Comment: In this particular case, just use a `std::span`.

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: its unclear how your actual code looks like, because the code you posted cannot compile https://godbolt.org/z/6E98Tsx51

Comment: something like this maybe https://godbolt.org/z/1eq68aT1c ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai exactly. I'll update the question.

Comment: @tkausl if I assign `_x` in the constructor (as shown), I have the same problem.

Comment: In the constructor you don't use an assignment, you use the member-initializer list..

Comment: @WeijunZhou - in this example it's possible. In real life the value may be a result of a complex calculation.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you use a helper function to calculate it and put that in the member-initializer list. Whether that is the best practice is another matter.

Comment: Having a reference as a member is not a good idea. Self-referenced objects are always trouble; they demand you to define copy and/or move constructor as well as assignment operator. Stick to accessor functions; they lead to simpler - yet more abstract - design.

Answer (score 2):

> I was advised to use const references instead of superfluous getter functions.

This advice does not agree with largely uncontroversial best practices: most classes should not have non-static data members which are reference types or const qualified.

See e.g. C++ core guidelines [here](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#define-copy-move-and-destroy-consistently) and [here](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-constref), or abseil's [TOTW 177](https://abseil.io/tips/177).

That is why copy operations do the wrong thing for Test.

However, even if you replace a const reference member with a const getter, you would still likely want to construct subset with the data in the constructor's member initializer list, e.g.:

```
template <typename Iter>
Test(Iter begin, Iter end) : _x{begin, end} {}

...

auto subset = Test{_x.begin() + i, _x.begin() + j};
```